# Why does this custom pointer class crash?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I am implementing a special purpose handle class.

`ihandle` is an interface that all handles must implement, in my real code it would have the operator overloadings for `->` `*`. But for this example, I wanted to keep it simple and it just has the `get` function.

```
template <typename T>
class ihandle {
public:
    virtual T* get();
};
```

One possible implementation would be `ptr`, which is just a raw pointer.

```
template <typename T>
class ptr : public ihandle<T>
{
    T* t;
public:
    ptr(T* t = nullptr) : t(t) {}
    T* get(){return t;}
};
```

And then there is `handle` which which is intended for doing null safety checks.

```
template <typename T>
class handle
{
public:
    ihandle<T>* h;

    T* get(){return h->get();}
    handle(ihandle<T>* h = nullptr) : h(h) {}

    template <typename D>
    handle(handle<D>& hd)
        : h((ihandle<T>*)hd.h)
    {
        static_assert(is_base_of<T, D>::value, "error");
    }
};
```

There is this constructor for being able to cast from a handle of an inheriting class to a handle of a base class.

```
template <typename D>
handle(handle<D>& hd)
    : h((ihandle<T>*)hd.h)
{
    static_assert(is_base_of<T, D>::value, "error");
}
```

For example, if `B` inherits from `A`, I would like to be able to call this function with an instance of `handle<B>`.

```
void foo(handle<A> ha) {
    // do something
}
```

But this gives a segfault for the following sample test.

```
struct A {
    virtual void talk() {printf("A\n");}
};

struct B : public A {
    void talk() {printf("B\n");}
};

int main()
{
    handle<B> hb(new ptr<B>(new B));
    //hb.get()->talk(); // if uncomment, no segfault
    handle<A> ha = hb;
    ha.get()->talk(); // segfault here

    return 0;
}
```

I suspect the problem might be in the `handle(handle<D>& hd)` constructor but I don't understand what's happening.

You can test it by clicking this link:
https://onlinegdb.com/BkAYuQZ3z

Comment: you don't have proper copy constructor for to work sanely `handle<A> ha = hb;`  ... mabbe rule of five and zero  is something you should look up

Answer (score 5):

Even if condition `is_base_of<T, D>::value` is true it does not make `(ihandle<T>*) hd.h` cast valid because `ptr<B>` and `ihandle<A>` types are not related. I guess this is an example of situation where c-style cast should be definitely avoided. To perform conversion safely you can utilize `dynamic_cast` with a check:

```
: h(dynamic_cast<ihandle<T>*>(hd.h))
{
   if(hd.h && !h)
   {
       throw ::std::runtime_error{"pointers are not related"};
   }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to allow up-casting from `handle<B>` to `handle<A>` also, `dynamic_cast` also allows down-casting from `handle<A>` to `handle<B>`. The `runtime_error` throws with the code you provided. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to make conversion `handle<B>` to `handle<A>` work then you will need to store only pointers to root target type (`ihandle<A> * h;` in both `handle<B>` and `handle<A>`) or make COM-like `QueryInterface` method.

Answer (score 1):

Q: what compiler/linker are you using ? when I compile your stuff using VS-2017, I get a linker error. It sais it expects a B->get() when I include the declaration of hb like in your main test,

```
handle<B> hb(new ptr<B>(new B));
```

..but when I provide some default implementation for the virtual method ihandle.get(), like this..

```
template <typename T>
class ihandle {
   public:
   virtual T* get() { return NULL; }
 };
```

return NULL.. my linker error is gone.. and there is no crash. You test reports B or B B.

Hope I can help. Thanks for the code ! I'm learning C++ atm, above example is a good study..

Comment: That's interesting, I was using gcc